# Angular: handling server error

Tags: angularjs

Am trying to handle server error in Angular app, in the browser console HTTP status code is 412 with an error message from a server in the response. I want to check the status code and show that message am getting from the server however it's both are undefined. check the code below there is a comment where the values is undefined.

Also, it is maybe useful to mention that am getting another error when the HTTP call fail with 412 status code which is `Unexpected token U in JSON at position` am not sure which part of the code expecting `json` and getting nothing so that error is produced.

```
function httpPromise(url, method, params, data) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: method,
                url: url,
                params: params,
                data: data
                })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('error', data); //undefined
                    console.log('status', status);//undefined
                    deferred.reject(data);

                });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a server issue the response returning from the server is not in JSON format

Answer (score 0):

In your WebAPI for error message, implement below class under App_start:

```
     public class HttpActionResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly string _message;
        private readonly HttpStatusCode _statusCode;

        public HttpActionResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        {
            _statusCode = statusCode;
            _message = message;
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(_statusCode)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(_message)
            };
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }

in controller use in try catch block:
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateInsertInfo(){
try
{
} 
   catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new HttpActionResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
```

in Angular handle like:

```
    this.service.updateInsertInfo(param).subscribe (resp => {
       if (resp === -1 ) {
        alert('Error occured whiile saving the information');
        return;
       } else {//  }
     },
     (error) => {
      console.log('POST ERROR in method updateInsertInfo: ' + error.error);
    });
```